# Flutter splash screen not showing

Tags: flutter, screen, splash-screen

I'am trying to add a splash screen on my application , i'am pretty sure i made all the steps correctly

I've added my picture on launch_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/1-ZID-SplashScreen" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And i have added the path of the picture which is located on drawable folder on pubsec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/google_fonts/
    - android/app/src/main/res/drawable/
```

But still the splash screen stills white, help me resolve this please ^^

Thanks.

Comment: As I know, the **ressource** should start with a **letter** not a **number** ; in your case `"android:src="@drawable/1-ZID-SplashScreen"` (google the _android ressources naming convention_ for more information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) it will help you achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can add a native splash screen to your app in 02 ways.

1. Using flutter package.

   This is the easiest way to add a splash screen for your flutter app.  (You don't need to have prior Native android & ios development knowledge).

   Link to package:- [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

   This video shows that how to use this package:- [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/8ME8Czqc-Oc)

---

2. Without using flutter package (Native way)

   For this method, you needed to have prior native android & ios development experience.

   If you had native development experience, you can use the below links to see the steps.

   [Link](https://ssaurel.medium.com/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857#.jxgci8kik)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the **ressource name** (in your case `"android:src="@drawable/1-ZID-SplashScreen"`) should start with a **letter** not a **number** (google the *android ressources naming convention* for more information).