# Flutter Splash Screen Still Showing Default Logo and Background Color Even After Modifications

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to Flutter, and I did try to switch the splash screen logo and the background color with methods below but failed. I have tried to Googled some solutions and tried but none have worked for me.

2 Methods mentioned below doesn't work for me. When I run the program, it still show the default splash screen ignoring my background image and logo. 2nd method is just to try commenting out the logo to see whether it would update the splash screen but it doesn't. I try my Samsung A53 5G and Android Emulator (Pixel 7 Pro API 33). For Method 1, I did check the drawable files, the images in the drawable are already updated so means it should already worked but it doesn't. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

[Default Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0hvD.png)

Method 1: Using Flutter Native Splash

[pubspec.yaml Snippet Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gydgn.png)

1. Added Dependencies on pubspec.yaml

[Execution of Creating Native Splash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8D0M.png)

2. on my Project Terminal I execute, dart run flutter_native_splash:create

Note: I am sure flutter pub get after adding the dependencies

Method 2: Manually Attempting to Comment out the Logo

For this method I try by going to android/app/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml Comment out
    `<item> <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/splash"/> </item>`

Method I have tried:

1. [Flutter splash screen not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964948/flutter-splash-screen-not-showing)
2. [Flutter splash screen doesn't update when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077097/flutter-splash-screen-doesnt-update-when-changed)
3. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146269/how-to-remove-flutters-default-splash-screen#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20default%20splash%20screen%20cannot,after%20the%20default%20splash%20screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146269/how-to-remove-flutters-default-splash-screen#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20default%20splash%20screen%20cannot,after%20the%20default%20splash%20screen)

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: Use this tool to create your custom splash screen : https://icon.kitchen/i/

Comment: Just tried this method and still not working for me, I also trying on other project with the same approach and the same result as well. Is there the possibilities of laptop being an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 12 introduced a new method of adding splash screens, and the `flutter_native_splash` package has its own setup for providing splash screens in Android 12+ (see the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#android-12-support)).

As a quick fix, you can do this:

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/splash_screen.png
  color_dark: "#1a1a1a"
  image_dark: assets/splash_screen.png
  
  # add this
  android_12:
    icon_background_color: "#FFFFFF"
    image: assets/splash_screen.png
    icon_background_color_dark: "#1a1a1a"
    image_dark: assets/splash_screen.png
```

Comment: This method works for me, I did tried adding android_12 just now but forgot to add the parameter, it seems like I need to add the image as well. Thanks a lot.